# Opencart use Category as parent for store ( multi store system )

Tags: php, list, menu, opencart, categories

Hy all,

I'm working on an multi store website.

The main store is [this](http://gospel7.com/). The second store ( same db, multi store ) is [this](http://www.life-shop.nl/index.php?route=common/home) `with uid 4`

I've got for the second store an categorie with multiple childs, with grand childs and so on...

My question is very simple, how can i make the categorie ( with `uid 355` ) the parent categorie for that store instead of `uid 0`

*I'll use VQMOD later, but i'm now inserting code directly in the files, for fast programming / debugging*

The file that i'm changing is in: `[root]/catalog/module/category.php`

I've changed this code:

```
public function getCategories($parent_id = 0) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'  AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)");

        return $query->rows;
    }
```

To this:

```
public function getCategories($parent_id = 0) {
        if( $this->config->get('config_store_id') == 4 && $parent_id == 0 ){
            $parent_id = 355;
            echo "test1";
        }
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'  AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)");

        return $query->rows;
    }
```

And that kinda works. At the home page, the wrong categorie menu list is gone ( there's no menu anymore ), and at an categorie list page like [this one](http://www.life-shop.nl/index.php?route=product/category&path=65_65) there are the right categorie's on the left.

If i delete the `&& $parent_id == 0` part, it goes wrong at both the page's.

Does anybody got an clue of how to fix it? Any help would be apriciated. If you need more info, i will give it to you.

*-ps- sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a lot of try's i searched the fora's of OpenCart better and came upon this thread:
[OpenCart Fora Thread](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=37667)

The anser there is as follows:
`There's a "top" flag you set to make it show up as a top level menu`

So what i did is this:

I've edited the new main category ( with `uid 355` ) and flagged it as top, that didn't helped, but i left it on.
Then i've edited all the direct childs of the main category and flagged them as top and foila, there they are. the problem was solved.

So with my edit to the main core, and the flagging of the categorie's, the problem is now solved